# Где посмотреть исходный код запроса ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Не понимаю, сделал обычный ajax запрос, что бы подгрузилась разметка, в браузере всё отображается, что надо, а заглянул в исходный код, а там пустота, почему, кто с таким сталкивался?

Comment: загляни в "проинспектировать элемент" а дом не привязан к коду страницы

Comment: Во вкладке elements присутствует, а ctrl+u там её нету

Comment: и не должно быть: дом не привязан к коду страницы

Comment: где эта кнопка находится в хроме?

Answer (score 1):

> В вашей версии Chrome панель может выглядеть несколько по-иному, но
>   что где находится, должно быть понятно.
>
> Зайдите на страницу с примером браузером Chrome.
>
> Откройте инструменты разработчика: F12 или в меню Инструменты >
>   Инструменты Разработчика.
>
> Выберите сверху Sources.

https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome